# Does Numpy dot and outer function consistent with Linear Algebra?

Tags: python, numpy

I was confused with matrix operation on Python Numpy. 
It seems that dot and outer operations don't behave like what I have learn in Linear Algebra class.

```
import numpy
n = numpy.arange(-5, 6)
w = numpy.arange(-20, 21)
n.shape
w.shape
outer = numpy.outer(w, n)
outer.shape
dot = numpy.dot(n, outer.transpose())
dot.shape
```

Here n is (11, 1) matrix, w is (41, 1) matrix. I think the size of w and n doesn't match.((41, 1) outer(11, 1))

Again, I think the dot is strange. n is (11, 1) matrix, outer.transpose() is (11, 41) matrix. I think the size is also not matched.

Comment: Have you read the Numpy documentation? What did it say? Did it clear up your confusion? First do your research, then ask your question.

Comment: Yes, I have read the doc. But I think I am still confused. If you know the answer, please do me a favor. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

According to  the documentation http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html , the `outer` function of two row vectors `A(1xn)` and `B(1xm)` is a matrix `M(nxm)` - and the transpose will be of dimension `mxn`. This is exactly what you are seeing.

Thus, the dot product of a vector and a matrix is again described in the documentation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html#numpy.dot - where it is essentially described as the matrix multiplication of the row vector (first argument) with the transpose of the second argument (matrix).

When I print out the shapes of the various objects your code creates, I get:

```
n.shape:     (11,)
w.shape:     (41,)
outer.shape: (41, 11)h
dot.shape:   (41,)
```

Which is entirely consistent with the above. What is your confusion? What result is not what you were expecting?

Comment: Yes, it does behave consistent with the documentation. However, it does behave differently comparing with the law of linear algebra. It turned out to be that numpy python is flexible. Numpy not only support  operation consistent with linear algebra operations. Numpy also support above interpretation, which is claimed in the documentation.

Comment: This "flexible at the expense of rigor" is a hallmark of Python. Instead of saying "you must transpose your first vector in order to take a proper outer product", the fact that you are explicitly asking for the outer product "is enough" for Numpy to figure out what you intended. This is convenient, but it can hide errors - in the same way that some languages don't require you to declare variables, but that this means you may find yourself scratching your head over a result because of a typo in a variable name.